# Updating date(time) in cell after selecting DatePicker

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, datepicker, textview

I'm currently an app that has a feature that allows users to add schedule(time)

Here's the progress I made so far
1. Added textview and datepicker and made the datepicker enable after tapping the textView
 
2. Time (the time I run the project) is displayed on each cell(as attached picture)

I want to display date(like 10:10PM in the screen short) in the cell after selecting time in datepicker, but unable to update the selected time.
 
Any ideas how to do this? 
 
Thanks in advance.

[image]

TimeSelectorViewController:

```
import UIKit

class TimeSelectorController: UICollectionViewController, 
UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UITextViewDelegate {

let cellId = "cellId"

let timeSelectorCell = TimeSelectorCell()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.backgroundColor = .yellow

    collectionView.reloadData()
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "V", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleBack))

    collectionView.register(TimeSelectorCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}


@objc fileprivate func handleBack() {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! TimeSelectorCell

    cell.textView.inputView = timeSelectorCell.timePicker
    cell.textView.text = timeSelectorCell.handleSelectedTime()

    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 50)
   }

}
```

TableSelectorCell:

```
import UIKit

class TimeSelectorCell: UICollectionViewCell {


let textView: UITextView = {
    let tv = UITextView()
    tv.text = "Time Goes Here"
    tv.isEditable = false
    return tv
}()

lazy var timePicker: UIDatePicker = {
    let picker = UIDatePicker()
    picker.datePickerMode = .time
    picker.minuteInterval = 10
    //picker.minuteInterval = 30
    picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSelectedTime), for: .valueChanged)
    return picker
}()

@objc func handleSelectedTime() -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    let selectTime = dateFormatter.string(from: timePicker.date)

    textView.inputView = timePicker
    textView.text = selectTime

    print(selectTime)

    return selectTime
}


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addSubview(textView)
    textView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, height: 0, width: 0)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `dateFormat` will be following for getting time in 12 Hours Format

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
```

Comment: Hi Nikunji, thanks for your response! it changed the format but the time didn't update. what I mean is that I want to display time (10:10PM) in the cell after selecting the time.

Comment: @akaak for that you need to store the selected time in an array and pass that array to your collectionview. when selecting the time for different cell you need to update that time in your array and reload the collection view.

Comment: @akaak what happens now when the value changes? nothing? Is your handleSelectedTime method called?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri handleSelectedTime method is indeed called. The problem is I can't update the time displayed. The textView "20:17" in the five cell is the time I runned the project. I'll try what Nikunj suggested

Comment: @akaak you want the time to reflect on all 5 cells? It is currently reflecting on one cell correct?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri none of the cells are reflected now. Actually, I want to display all different time on each cell.